# R Compare duplicate values ​for each row in two data sets

Tags: r

I want to compare whether the values ​​in each row are the same.
In this case, duplicated and all_equal function are not suitable.

**Reproducible Sample Data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6))
df2 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,4),b=c(4,5,6))

> df1
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
> df2
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 4 6
```

**Expected output**

```
final <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,4),b=c(4,5,6),c=c('T','T','F'))
#c column is the result I need. whether the values ​​in each row are the same.

>final
  a b c
1 1 4 T
2 2 5 T
3 4 6 F
```

I try method below... but This is complicated.

```
#1. making idx of df1, df2
#2. and full_join
#3. and left_join df1
#4. and left_join df2
```

```
df1$idx1 <- 1:nrow(df1)
df2$idx2 <- 1:nrow(df2)

df3<-full_join(df1,df2,by=c('a','b'))
df3<-left_join(df3,df1,by=c('a','b'))
df3<-left_join(df3,df2,by=c('a','b'))  #This may or may not work..
```

I think there must be a better way. help!

Answer (score 2):

We could use

```
df2$c <- Reduce(`&`, Map(`==`, df1, df2))
```

-output

```
> df2
  a b     c
1 1 4  TRUE
2 2 5  TRUE
3 4 6 FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get column 'c' by:

```
c <- df1$a == df2$a & df1$b == df2$b
```

gives TRUE  TRUE FALSE. It looks like you want to then bind this to df2, so

```
cbind.data.frame(df2, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `rowSums` -

```
final <- df2
final$c <- rowSums(df1 != df2) == 0
final

#  a b     c
#1 1 4  TRUE
#2 2 5  TRUE
#3 4 6 FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the positions of the rows in each `data.frame` do not matter you can use `merge`.

```
within(merge(df2, within(df1, c <- "T"), all.x=TRUE), c[is.na(c)] <- "F")
#  a b c
#1 1 4 T
#2 2 5 T
#3 4 6 F
```

or using `duplicated`.

```
df2$c <- c("F", "T")[1+tail(duplicated(rbind(df1, df2)), nrow(df2))]
df2
#  a b c
#1 1 4 T
#2 2 5 T
#3 4 6 F
```